# Heroku RACK_ENV remains “production”

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, environment-variables

I’ve set the environment variable `RACK_ENV` to `staging` via heroku_san’s configuration file (as well as manually).
When listing all ENV variables, it shows correctly as being set to "staging". If I check via the console I’m getting a correct result as well.

However, if I log it within my application_controller, it appears to be "production". Any idea why and how to correct this? 
`RAILS_ENV` is set to "production". I’m guessing that this might cause the problem. Can’t these two differ from each other?

Answer (score 2):

Rails looks for RAILS_ENV first, then for RACK_ENV. I guess, Heroku sets RAILS_ENV to production by default and it takes precedence over RACK_ENV. Try to set RAILS_ENV environment variable to "staging" directly.

And if that doesn't work, you should log ENV in your application controller, so that we can see what are all the environment variables from inside.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. `RAILS_ENV` is defined (and set to "production"). I had logged `ENV['RACK_ENV']` and it returns "production". I’d like to keep Rails in production and only set `RACK_ENV` to "staging". Does that make sense?

Comment: Ah, now I get it. Did you use `heroku config` for listing variables? What console did you use, `rails console` or `irb`?

Comment: Can you log and compare the whole ENV in both places? Maybe you are running the console and the server on different machines.